# Can't fill the height of the window with my navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having this problem with the menu in my code.
I wanted to do a navbar that on the PC screen fill the height on the left side, and make it scrolleable on the top in mobile version.

The problem is that my flex container doesn't fill the height of the screen,it's getting off on the bottom..
Here's my code:

```css
/* css */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#main-doc {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#container-nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 13.35em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

#nav-header {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.nav-link {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  background: green;
}

#container-nav {
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  #container-nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 20%;
    border-right: none;
  }
  #main-doc {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
  #nav-header {
    flex: 0;
  }
  .nav-link {
    flex: 0;
    padding: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- html -->
<main id="main-doc">

  <nav id="navbar">
    <div id="container-nav">
      <header class="nav-link" id="nav-header">Flexbox Documentation</header>

      <a src=# class="nav-link">About</a>
      <a src=# class="nav-link">Basics</a>
      <a src=# class="nav-link">Flex Container Properties</a>
      <a src=# class="nav-link">Flex Items Properties</a>
      <a src=# class="nav-link">Examples</a>

    </div>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Comment: Hi, from what I see from your code, the left navbar is filling the height 100%.

Comment: For the height 100% screen, you need to add `height: 100vh` not `100vw`

Comment: You trying to make something like this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `vh`?

`1vh` is relative to 1% of the screen's height, so trying setting your `height` to `100vw`

E.G. `#container-nav { height: 100vh; }`

[More Info Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of making a column full-height is related to the ['Holy Grail' layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_grail_(web_design)) and has been solved by [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/) and [grid](https://css-tricks.com/books/volume-i/holy-grail-layout-5-lines-css/) for a while.

But as mentioned, top-most container should be set to `min-height: 100vh` for this to work. Use `min-height` instead of `height` to allow the element to extend if required.

Additionally, I've cleaned up that HTML by a) removing unnecessary elements, classes and ids, b) moving the `header` outside of the `nav` and c) putting your nav links into a `ul` with correct `href` attributes instead of `src`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2rem;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
nav li {
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
}
nav a {
  background-color: green;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2rem;
}
main p {
  height: 200rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {

  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

}
```

```html
<body>

  <header></header>
  
  <nav>
    <h1>Flexbox Documentation</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Basics</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Flex Container Properties</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Flex Items Properties</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <main>
    <p>Main content</p>
  </main>
  
</body>
```